# string a = "1,2,3" string b = "4,5,6" required answer c = (1,4), (2,5), (3,6) in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have two strings

```
a = "1,2,3" 
b = "4,5,6"
```

how can i achieve this result `c =  "(1,4), (2,5), (3,6)"`. I have already tried many solution but no success

Comment: Share one of your attempts and someone can point you to your mistake. Solving homework is not the purpose of SO.

Comment: a = "1,2,3".split(',')
b = "4,5,6".split(',')
c = a.product(b)

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer? I suggest that, in future, you wait awhile--perhaps a couple of hours anyway.  You don't want to discourage others from answering and it's a courtesy, imo, to give others still working on answers some time to post them before you make a selection.

Comment: This also works, even though it's an abomination: `a.split(',').map { |s| "(#{s}, " }.zip(b.split(',').map { |s| "#{s})" }).map { |f,s| f+s }.join(', ')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Array#zip to create an array of pairs.

```
a.split(',').zip(b.split(',')).map { |x, y| "(#{x},#{y})" }.join(', ')
```

Comment: this is way better than what I'm doing. +1

Answer (score 1):

Use `zip` instead of `product`. Here:

```
puts a.split(',').map(&:to_i).zip(b.split(',').map(&:to_i)).to_s.tr('[]', '()')
# ((1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6))
```

Explaining Steps:

- `a.split(',')` will split Array. (`["1", "2", "3"]`)
- `.map(&:to_i)` will convert Array elements to integer (`[1, 2, 3]`)
- `.zip` will merge the two Arrays in desired way.
- I'm using two `tr` to replace `[]` with `()`.

Comment: @ChetanRana If it solved your problem please mark it as solution.

Comment: This produces `((1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6))` whereas the OP wants `(1,4), (2,5), (3,6)`

Comment: BTW, you can use `tr('[]', '()')` instead of the two `gsub`s

Comment: @Stefan thanks for suggesting `tr`. I have edited my answer based on your comment :)

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'json'
((JSON.load("[#{a}]").zip JSON.load("[#{b}]")).to_s.tr'[]','()')[1...-1]
```